# Proc sql FIFO function

Tags: sas, enter

I face with some interesting task. How to generate a FIFO loop for my data set?
We have losses and recoveries.
losses:
[image: Loses]

Recoveries:

[image: Recoveries]

Using FIFO scheme I should get this table (loses)

[image]

Do you have any idea how to get this result?)) Using SAS Data step or Proc sql.

```
data have1;
    input id$ date:mmddyy10. loss_amt;
    format date date9.;
    datalines;
id1 01.01.2019 100000
id1 02.05.2019 200000
id1 03.06.2019 300000
id1 04.12.2019 500000
id2 02.05.2019 200000
;
run;

data have2;
    input id$ date:mmddyy10. recovery_amt;
    format date date9.;

    datalines;
id1 01.01.2019 50000
id1 02.06.2019 150000
id1 03.06.2019 110000
id1 04.05.2020 100000
id2 02.07.2019 200000
;
run;
```

I ve read some article about SAS Hash object but I do not understand how exactly apple this function to my data. Now I am trying to find out

Comment: How do you end up with id1 remains 200,000 when recovery has a date in 2020 ?  How does a 4/12/2019 value get affected by something happening on 4/5/2020 ?  Premise is 200,000 = 100,000 + 200,000 + 300,000 + 500,000 - 50,000 - 150,000 - 600,000 - 100,000

Comment: I am sorry I ve made couple mistakes while preparing this Data)

Comment: Why does only the last row in a group get a value for `remains` ? Should the result be more simply one row per group ? Also, I recommend removing the first two images now that you have add `data steps` with datalines.  Add another data step with datalines for the `wanted` table and you can remove that last image.  Finally, a FIFO operation is essentially a forward serial process and your processing might be achieved with just `MERGE` and  `BY id` statements

Comment: How do you see it Richard?